# IIS - Deny public access to all files in specified directory

Tags: .htaccess, iis-7, web-config

I need to translate a .htaccess file to web.config for use on IIS 7.5:

```
IndexIgnore */*
<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

This is intended to prevent public access to any file in the /core directory by locating the file at /core/.htaccess.

The application still requires access to php files and other assets from the /core directory.

I tried *hiddenSegments*:

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
            <add segment="core"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

and *denyUrlSequences*:

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <denyUrlSequences>
            <add sequence="/core/" />
        </denyUrlSequences>
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

however these prevent the admin panel from functioning as requests like the following are blocked:

```
http://www.domain.com/admin/assets/core/admin.js
```

because the URL contains the blocked sequence *core*.

Can anyone suggest how public access to resources in the /core directory can be prevented while allowing the admin panel to function?

Answer (score 4):

I've implemented a solution by placing the following web.config in the directory that URL access should be denied for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- prevent url access to this and sub directories -->
        <denyUrlSequences>
          <add sequence="/" />
        </denyUrlSequences>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```